# infinite loop to detect the newest file

Tags: java, file

I need to run an infinite loop which displays the name of a newly created file where a new file is detected in a repository then stoped it until a new one is created.

```
        String directoryPath = "/home/Maria/Bureau/file/"; 
        File directory = new File(directoryPath); 

        File moreRecentFile = null; 
        File[] subfiles = directory.listFiles(); 
        if( subfiles.length > 0 )
        {
            moreRecentFile = subfiles[0]; 

        for (int i = 1; i < subfiles.length; i++) 

        { 
            File subfile = subfiles[i]; 

        if (subfile.lastModified() > moreRecentFile.lastModified())
            moreRecentFile = subfile;
        }

        System.out.println(moreRecentFile.getName()); 

        }
```

I wrote this code which detects the newly created file, I want to know how can I add this loop.

Comment: Why not use the [`WatchService` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to let the filesystem detect the changes for you?

Comment: I have no idea about WatchService

Comment: @MariaBaccar I added answer with docs links and example

Comment: @MariaBaccar You already got a link there.

Answer (score 0):

Modern OS and filesystems, AFAIK, supports so called Filesystem events, where you create a listener and receive events about filesystem changes, including new files creation events.

F.e. from Oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

```
for (;;) {

    // wait for key to be signaled
    WatchKey key;
    try {
        key = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        return;
    }

    for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

        // This key is registered only
        // for ENTRY_CREATE events,
        // but an OVERFLOW event can
        // occur regardless if events
        // are lost or discarded.
        if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
            continue;
        }

        // The filename is the
        // context of the event.
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
        Path filename = ev.context();

        // Verify that the new
        //  file is a text file.
        try {
            // Resolve the filename against the directory.
            // If the filename is "test" and the directory is "foo",
            // the resolved name is "test/foo".
            Path child = dir.resolve(filename);
            if (!Files.probeContentType(child).equals("text/plain")) {
                System.err.format("New file '%s'" +
                    " is not a plain text file.%n", filename);
                continue;
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
            continue;
        }

        // Email the file to the
        //  specified email alias.
        System.out.format("Emailing file %s%n", filename);
        //Details left to reader....
    }

    // Reset the key -- this step is critical if you want to
    // receive further watch events.  If the key is no longer valid,
    // the directory is inaccessible so exit the loop.
    boolean valid = key.reset();
    if (!valid) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Another good link with example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice

Comment: does Watcheservice available for JDK 1.6?

Comment: @MariaBaccar Afraid no, these classes are available since Java 1.7 as per javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html